# Using any material-ui component results in error in the <WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField))> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

`App.js` contains the following:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';


class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <TextField id="time" type="time" />
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

This error is returned in the browser console and nothing is rendered:

```
The above error occurred in the <WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField))> component:
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(TextField)) (created by App)
    in App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html to learn more about error boundaries. react-dom.development.js:16013:13

TypeError: react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default.a.useContext is not a function main.js line 1932 > eval:9:55
    useTheme webpack:///./node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/useTheme/useTheme.js?:9
    makeStyles webpack:///./node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/makeStyles/makeStyles.js?:233
    WithStyles webpack:///./node_modules/@material-ui/styles/esm/withStyles/withStyles.js?:65
    React 22
        updateForwardRef
        beginWork
        performUnitOfWork
        workLoop
        callCallback
        invokeGuardedCallbackDev
        invokeGuardedCallback
        replayUnitOfWork
        renderRoot
        performWorkOnRoot
        performWork
        performSyncWork
        requestWork
        scheduleWork
        scheduleRootUpdate
        updateContainerAtExpirationTime
        updateContainer
        render
        legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer
        unbatchedUpdates
        legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer
        render
    <anonymous> webpack:///./leadmanager/frontend/src/components/App.js?:57
    js http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/main.js:97
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/main.js:20
    <anonymous> webpack:///./leadmanager/frontend/src/index.js?:2
    js http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/main.js:109
    __webpack_require__ http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/main.js:20
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/main.js:84
    <anonymous> http://localhost:8000/static/frontend/main.js:87
```

If `<TextField id="time" type="time" />` is replaced with `<h1>Test</h1>` the application runs with no problems. The same error results when using other components such as checkboxes.

What is causing this error and how to use material-ui components?

Comment: This code should be working fine: https://codesandbox.io/embed/staging-framework-gnhv0 The problem is probably somewhere else? Or maybe try removing @material-ui/core an re-adding it or something?

Comment: What version of React are you using? The updated error log looks like you're using a version of React that doesn't support hooks yet.

Comment: @jagsler 16.7.0, just checked and 16.8.0 seems to be the first version using hooks. Will try upgrading and report back

Comment: @jagsler I think that you're on the money but will take a little longer to check as it's an existing repository so will need to do a few updates, including updating other dependencies.

Comment: Alright, good luck!